# ReactiveCocoa 4 - Creating a dependent login request that runs only once

Tags: reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-4

I've mostly been using ReactiveCocoa in the past to simply bind views and view models, and now I'm trying to take the plunge and use it throughout a new project but I'm having trouble getting my head around a couple of things.

What I want to do is this -

- Have a networked login request that every other network request needs to call first.
- If multiple requests are made, they all need to wait until log in completes (eg, let's say I've got a Tab Bar Controller and I quickly tap between them before log in finishes; I don't want multiple login requests fired.)

I've spent a bit of time exploring a few options like queues, looking into things like `flatMap(.Latest)` but if I'm completely honest - I have no idea what I'm doing! :S

Below's a very basic, dumb implementation which is quickly hacked together and very likely badly implemented. If someone could give me a few pointers into what I need to change it'd be enormously appreciated. My `doSomething` method obviously logs in first, but if multiple calls are made at once they don't wait until the first one finishes as I need them to.

Can I do something with the `loginValid` property?

(Also, pointers on generally how I should be structuring this stuff would be great - I'm sure I'm doing many stupid things with this code)

Thanks!

```
class FakeBackend: BackendType {

    private var loginResponse = MutableProperty<LoginResponse?>(nil)
    private let loginValid = MutableProperty<Bool>(false)

    private var loginProducer: SignalProducer<LoginResponse, NSError>! // <-- implicitly unwrapped optional? Yuck

    init() {
        loginValid <~ loginResponse.producer.map { $0 != nil }

        loginProducer = SignalProducer { [weak self] observer, disposable in
            guard let _self = self else { return }

            if let loginResponse = _self.loginResponse.value {
                print("Already have login details")
                observer.sendNext(loginResponse)
                observer.sendCompleted()
            } else {
                print("Don't have login details, go get them")
                _self.logIn().start(observer)
            }
        }
    }

    func doSomething() -> SignalProducer<HomeResponse, NSError> {
        return loginProducer
            .then(SignalProducer<HomeResponse, NSError> { observer, dispoable in

                let homeResponse = HomeResponse(title: "My title is this")

                observer.sendNext(homeResponse)
                observer.sendCompleted()
            })
    }

    private func logIn() -> SignalProducer<LoginResponse, NSError> {
        return SignalProducer { observer, disposable in

            print("Calling network login")
            delayToMainThread(1.0, closure: { [weak self] () -> () in

                guard let _self = self else { return }

                let loginResponse = LoginResponse(accessToken: "MyAccessToken")

                _self.loginResponse.value = loginResponse

                observer.sendNext(loginResponse)
                observer.sendCompleted()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is via `replayLazily`, which is described at https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/06/29/replay-replaylast-replaylazily/

> The -replayLazily convenience method returns a new signal that, when
>   subscribed to, will immediately send the subscriber the entire history
>   of values that have come through the source signal, without
>   re-executing the source signal’s subscription code.

I received a response to my question on the ReactiveCocoa Github Issues page. https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/2706

Essentially, you want to do something like this -

```
class FakeBackend: BackendType {

    private var login: SignalProducer<LoginResponse, NSError>

    init() {
        login = SignalProducer { observer, disposable in
            print("Logging in...")

            // we'd actually make a network call here, but for demo purposes
            // let's just return some dummy data.
            let loginResponse = LoginResponse(accessToken: "MyAccessToken")

            print("Logged in!")

            observer.sendNext(loginResponse)
            observer.sendCompleted()
        }.replayLazily(1)
    }

    func loadHomeScreen() -> SignalProducer<HomeResponse, NSError> {
        return login
            .flatMap(.Latest, transform: homeResponse)
    }

    private func homeResponse(loginResponse: LoginResponse) -> SignalProducer<HomeResponse, NSError> {
        return SignalProducer<HomeResponse, NSError> { observer, disposable in
            print("Aaaand, we've gotten our HomeResponse.")

            let homeResponse = HomeResponse(title: "My title is this")
            observer.sendNext(homeResponse)
            observer.sendCompleted()
        }
    }
}
```